# while i am running curl command showing error as {"ResponseJSON":{"Exception":"","Status":"500000"}}

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Below is the dss error while i am running esb and also esb is showing an error as {"ResponseJSON":{"Exception":"","Status":"500000"}} so, what does it mean?can one help me.

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:clientid
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: mparameter_DataService
Location: /mparameter_DataService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: mparameter
Current Params: {parameterid=}

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.getReader(DSOMDataSource.java:116)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getDirectReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:225)
    ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means , the request message which you are sending to the dataservice doesn't contain an element for 'clientid'. But the dataservice has been defined to be invoked with clientid. As per the error log, the parameters recieved by the dataservice is {parameterid=}, which should contain the clientid.

Comment: when i am testing at soap side proper data is coming and i also tested in query at sql side also giving proper data...

Comment: If you can post your proxy configuration and the input request message, that would be more useful to find out where is the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894787/my-sequence-is-too-long-so-please-go-through-this(please go through this link)

Comment: You can put a full log in the place of <log level="custom"/>, and check whether the correct input message getting send to dataservice. Do you have anywhere used 'parameterid'?

Comment: i already tried with <log level="full"/>..but same thing i got