# my sequence is too long,so please go through this

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Below is my sequence i am filtering based on clientid and modifiedon,it is giving proper data when i am running at soap side as well as query is fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ParameterMobile_Seq">

   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="WorkPartyBranchId"
             expression="//WorkPartyBranchId/text()"/>
   <log level="full">
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                name="kk"
                expression="get-property('Authentication')"/>
   </log>
   <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
           xpath="get-property('Authentication')='false'">
      <then>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                  <Exception>Authentication Failed</Exception>
                  <Status>404</Status>
               </ResponseJSON>
            </format>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
         <send/>
         <log level="full"/>
      </then>
      <else>
      <log level="full"/>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <p:mparameter xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                 <p:clientid>$1</p:clientid>
                 <p:modifiedon>$2</p:modifiedon>               
              </p:mparameter>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg expression="get-property('clientid')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('modifiedon')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
          <log level="custom"/>
         <send receive="ParameterMobile_Seq2">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/mparameter_DataService/" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
         <log level="full"/>
      </else>
   </filter>
</sequence>
```

This is only the sequence,please check and revert me.And showing an exception as 500000.so can we esplain in the em

Answer (score 0):

In the filter mediator, `then` condition you are trying to send request back to the client as response. So, you need to remove the "`To`" header.
The "`else`" condition looks fine. What is the issue now you are facing and at which configuration segment you are facing the issue?

Comment: i am trying to filter my service based on two parameters that is clientid and modifiedon and my curl command is looks like this curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "username:avinash|214057357158656" -H  "password:sps123" -d '{}' http://localhost:8282/services/Get_Parameter_Mobile